# How do I pass a single char properly as a reference to another method in C

Tags: c, string, pass-by-reference, arrays

Ok, I've been trying to crack this one for a while now.  I'm quite sure I'm lacking some sort of fundamental knowledge with how strings and chars work in C.

I have a method where I'm getting coordinates for a move on a checkers board.  So the user should input A1, B2 to signal that they want to move from square A1 to B2. It looks like this:

```
void get_desired_move(void)
{
    char    Ocol,
            Orow,
            Dcol,
            Drow,
            format;

    char move[7];

    printf("Please enter your next move (Origin Coordinate, Destination Coordinate): ");
    gets(move);

    endl(); // method I wrote for line break

    sscanf(move, "%c%c%c %c%c", &Ocol, &Orow, &format, &Drow, &Dcol);


    if(format == ',')
        validate_input(&Ocol, &Orow);

}
```

Then validate_input():

```
int validate_input(char *col, char *row)
{
    int colInt = *col-0x041;
    int isDig = isValidDigit(row);
    int rowInt = atoi(row);
    if(rowInt >=1 && rowInt <=8 && colInt >= 1 && colInt <= 8)
    {
        if(atoi(row) > 0 && atoi(row) < 8)
        {
            return true;
        }
}
```

When Orow from `get_desired_move()` gets passed to *row in `validate_input` it adds whatever letter was passed from Ocol to it.  So in the debugger I can see

```
Dcol    char    '2'
Drow    char    'B'
format  char    ','
move    char [7]    
Ocol    char    'A'
Orow    char    '1'
```

And once I get to `validate_data()` suddenly row is:

```
row char *  0xbffff20a "1A"
col char *  0xbffff20b "A"
colInt  int -1073745399
```

Why is the A being added onto my 1?  Is it because I dont have a null terminator for char pointer row?  And if so how do I resolve this?  isValidDigit is method I have that loops through a char array and because of the added "A" it fails... not too mention its driving me crazy that I can't understand whats going on.  Thanks everyone.

**EDIT**

---

Ok so after the help ( THANKS! ) I understand a little bit better about how things are passed around in C and also realize that I have a crap ton more to learn.  Either way my revised validate_input method now looks like this:

```
bool validate_input(char row, char col)
{
    if(&& atoi(&row) >=1 && atoi(&row) <=8 && col >= 'A' && col <= 'H')
    {
            return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

@ Bit Fiddling Code Monkey Thanks!

Comment: In C all function arguments are passed by value, however using pointer function arguments, one can mimic a call by reference, but still the pointer is passed by value.

Comment: I think I remember reading that.  Either way, even if I'm mimicking a call by reference, Im still clueless as to why the A is being attached to my variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very much overcomplicating things.  This will do the trick (assuming you've scanned the `stdin` input correctly):

```
// Rows: 1 to 8
// Cols: A to H

bool validate_input(char col, char row)
{
    if((col >= 'A') && (col <= 'H') && (row >= '1') && (row <= '8'))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Note:

1. I'm returning a bool.  It can only be true or false.
2. I'm passing the value of col and row, not the address.  It's only one character so the address is not really needed.

Comment: I have a tendancy of overcomplicating things.  I always thought it was good practice to pass by reference when you can.  Even though, I've now learned that there isn't really a pass by reference in C.  I was going to have a do while loop in validate data to get the input again if it was false but I suppose I could do that before I call validate_input using the returned bool from validate_input.  But thanks!  I still wish I knew why that A was being tagged on the end of my number....

Comment: @ChrisShields It must have something to do with, like you said, the nature of strings needing to be `'\0'` terminated.  Both `row` and `col` are right next to each other in memory and `*col` had a value of `'A'`.  `row` and `col` were not proper C strings.

Comment: @ChrisShields - It is absolutely NOT good practice to pass by reference if you don't need to.  Passing by value ensures that a called function won't corrupt your input data, intentionally or by accident.  Only values that the called function expects to change should be passed by reference.  (This is, of course, a style issue rather than a hard-and-fast rule.  The purpose is to be as clear as possible about what will happen on a call.)

Comment: @ErikJohnson Well said!

Comment: @Erik Johnson.   Ok, thanks for the explanation.  I originally thought it was better to try and avoid creating new variables where possible.  Also originally I was going to have  a do while loop in the `validate_input()` which would have infact changed the values.  Now with this solution by @Bit Fiddling Code Monkey I can avoid having to do that.  Also if I understand correctly if I'm passing a value which is smaller than the size of a reference I'm in fact working against myself?

Comment: @ChrisShields The `sizeof` a pointer depends on the platform it's running on but it's pretty safe to assume `sizeof(char *) > sizeof(char)`.

Comment: @ChrisShields If you consider passing a larger piece of data than necessary to be working against yourself, then yes.  But the comparative sizes is irrelevant - in either case it's stored as a single CPU register.  The key is that passing a pointer is more dangerous than passing a value. (Pointer, not reference.  C has no references.  Thinking of a pointer as just a reference is a very bad habit.)  There are a number of things you can do to a pointer that can cause your program to fail in difficult-to-debug ways.